# Custom select on join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using rails 3.2, and trying to use ActiveRecord to query my database.
I have 2 activerecord models, Admin and Order:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :orders
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :operation
  belongs_to :admin
```

In my case, order.operation is a string, representing order type. I'm trying to build a query giving me three columns:

```
admin.name, admin.orders.where(:operation => 'bonus').count, admin.orders.where(:operation => 'gift').count
```

Is there a way to fit it in a single query?

EDITED: 
here's raw sql to get what I need:

```
SELECT t_a.admin_id_com, t_a.name, gb_f_f_gb_f_fi.bonus_count, gb_f_f_gb_f_fi.gifts_count 
FROM (
  SELECT f_fil.admin_id_gifts, f_fil.gifts_count, f_filt.admin_id_bonus, f_filt.bonus_count 
  FROM (
    SELECT admin_id as admin_id_gifts, count(distinct id) as gifts_count FROM orders WHERE operation = 'new gifts!' GROUP BY admin_id_gifts) 
  f_fil LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT admin_id as admin_id_bonus, count(distinct id) as bonus_count FROM orders WHERE operation = 'new bonuses!' GROUP BY admin_id_bonus) 
  f_filt ON (f_fil.admin_id_gifts = f_filt.admin_id_bonus)) 
gb_f_f_gb_f_fi LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT id AS admin_id_com, t_ad.name FROM admins t_ad) t_a ON (gb_f_f_gb_f_fi.admin_id_gifts = t_a.admin_id_com)
```

Is it possible to buid a query like that using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Do you want the aggregate column column calculations based on (i.e. grouped by) the `admin.name` column?

Comment: Yep, .group(:admin_id) would be good, but that's not the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Can you tell me what you're having trouble with (e.g. show what you've tried)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@admins   = Admin.joins(:orders).
                 select("admins.id, admins.name, orders.id, 
                          SUM((orders.operation = 'bonus')::integer) AS bonus_count, 
                          SUM((orders.operation = 'gift')::integer) AS gift_count ").
                 group("admins.id ")

# access each columns as
admin.name, admin.bonus_count, admin.gift_count
```

Other option is to use eager loading, it will use two queries but might be faster

```
@admins  = Admin.includes(:orders)

# in admin.rb
def orders_count(type)
  # Don't use where here as it would make a separate query instead of using eager loading records
   orders.select{|x| x.operation == type}.count
end 

# access each columns as
admin.name, admin.orders_count("bonus"), admin.orders_count("gift")
```

Comment: I have changed `SUM` to `COUNT`, and it works, but not the way it should. It counts all orders both in `bonus_count` and in `gift_count` . Here's what I got: `t.map {|a| [a.name, a.bonus_count, a.gift_count]}` - `[["test", "10", "10"]]`

Comment: does it not work with `SUM`? `count` won't work as it will just count all the orders. Idea with `sum` is that `operations=bonus` is 1 when true and 0 when false so summing it should count only orders with `operation = bonus`

Comment: It doesn't work with sum, at least it doesn't work for me on my heroku postgres =(

Comment: Not familiar with heroku postgres but it seems postgres has the sum functionality..see [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/)...what does it say when you use SUM?

Comment: So, I finally found time to test your code (first variant). It works, you only should add cast to integer: `(orders.operation = 'bonus')::integer`. Correct that and I will mark your answer accepted. But still, I find my query better.

Comment: updated with your suggestion, your edit was somehow rejected before I could accept it.